# rails generate paper_trail:install needs access to database?

Tags: mysql, paper-trail-gem

When I try to run `rails generate paper_trail:install [--with-changes]` it wants to access the database, but at that point the database is not yet running.

1: from /local-home//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1@Project/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `initialize' /local-home//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1@Project/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in` connect': Access denied for user 'xxx'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError)

There are no migrations running as per the documentation.

How to avoid this?
Why does it want to access the database?

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] See https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/pull/1308

This solution adds a flag to the installer to set --mysql so it won't have to make a database connection.